# Storing list of users associated with a certain item

Tags: mysql, sql, database, organization

This is a bit hard to explain.

But i have built an app where users create what i like to call 'raffles' and then users subscribe to it.

I have a table for the raffles, and i could have a column of type text in it and store all the users in it separated by commas(,)

or i could create a separate table where users are added and associated to the raffle via another field called 'raffle_id' or something like it.

I'm not sure how effective both of these methods will be efficient in the long run or for scaling.

Some advise would be appreciated.

Comment: How many users and raffles do you expect to have?

Comment: I'm expecting a minimum of 30-100

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against storing your user information in CSV format.  The main reason for this is that CSV will make querying the table by user difficult.  It will also make doing updates difficult.  SQL databases were designed to handle *relational* data using tables.  So in your case I would design the `raffles` table to look like thia:

```
raffles (raffle_id, user_id)
```

And the data might look like this:

```
1 1
1 3
1 7
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 6
```

In other words, each record corresponds to a single `raffle`-`user` relation.  Assuming that you only have a few dozen users and raffles happen every so often, thia should scale fine.  And if this `raffles` table ever gets too large at a much later date you can archive a portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

See [What is the best way to add users to multiple groups in a database?][1]

Raffles are the "Groups". "UserInGroup" becomes UserInRaffle, your join table.